# Is there any point of "reference of pointer"?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, auto

I can't understand how reference of pointer type works.

1. Is there any performance difference?
2. Is there any assembly level difference if they compiled?
3. Is there any point to reference of pointer type?

```
vector<Figure*> vFigureList;

//auto&
for(auto& pFigure : vFigureList)
{
    pFigure->draw();
    delete pFigure;
}

//auto
for(auto pFigure : vFigureList)
{
    pFigure->draw();
    delete pFigure;
}

//Figure*
for(Figure* pFigure : vFigureList)
{
    pFigure->draw();
    delete pFigure;
}

//Figure*&
for(Figure*& pFigure : vFigureList)
{
    pFigure->draw();
    delete pFigure;
}
```

Comment: In your examples, when you use a reference you tell the comiler: *I mean that one!* When don't use a reference, you tell it: *I mean a copy of that one!* That are two very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once compiled, references are just like pointers, they provide a level of indirection.  However they have different use in C++:

- They must be initialized upon definition, hence safer, like a const pointer.
- No need to use the address of `&` operator to declare where they point to.
- No need to deference using `*`.

> Is there any performance difference?

Yes, references incur a level of pointer dereference, just like a normal pointer.

> Is there any assembly level difference if they compiled?

Compared to a plain variable, yes, an extra level of indirection.  Compared to a pointer, no, references and pointers are the same once compiled.

> Is there any point to reference of pointer type?

Yes, if you needed a pointer to a pointer, but wanted the safety and convenience of a reference.

Here's an example on Compiler Explorer (same source below in case link expires):
https://godbolt.org/z/h3WzdPWa1

When compiled with no optimization (not recommended, just for illustration with this Compiler Explorer example):

- Direct access uses three assembly instructions
- One level of indirection (pointers and references) uses five instructions
- Two levels of indirection (reference to pointer and pointer to pointer) uses seven instructions

This helps illustrate that references are really pointers under the hood, with the same performance implications.

```
int num();
int* num_ptr();

int main() {
    int i = num();
    
    int& r = i;
    int* p = num_ptr();

    int*& pr = p;
    int** pp = &p;

    // Direct access
    i += 3;

    // One level of indirection
    r += 5;   
    *p += 7;

    // Two levels of indirection
    *pr += 11;
    **pp += 13;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Compiled with no optimization" is a really bad indication. For instance, many optimizers are aware of another rule that you didn't mention: there are null pointers, but not null references.

Comment: Agree, optimization will improve performance.

No optimization was mentioned just in the context of this Compiler Explorer example to illustrate the levels of indirection.  With optimization enabled, even just -O1, GCC throws away the num() result and sees through all the pointer access and skips straight to adding 31 to num_ptr()'s result.

Answer (score 2):

> 3. Is there any point to reference of pointer type?

When you want to perform modification on them. e.g.

```
// when modify pointers themselves in vFigureList
for(auto& pFigure : vFigureList)
{
    delete pFigure;
    pFigure = nullptr; // modify pointers (in vFigureList) to nullptr
}
```

Basically it's the same as the difference between `int` and `int&`.

Comment: Maybe a nitpick, but still: What is the difference compared to just `for( auto pFigure : vFigureList )`? In the question's snippet, a plain pointer will have the same semantics, right?

Comment: @André Given `for( auto pFigure : vFigureList )`, `pFigure` is a copy and any modification on it has nothing to do with the pointers in `vFigureList`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your `pFigure = nullptr`. You are right of course. For the deletion it does not matter, because that will work on any copy of the pointer. But the resettig to `nullptr` must be done on the actual pointer in the list. Perhaps you could clarify that in the answer, too ;-)?

Answer (score 1):

References tend to be implemented as pointers, so your `Figure*&` is essentialy a pointer-to-pointer.

> Is there any performance difference?

> Is there any assembly level difference if they compiled?

References need to be dereferenced before use, however the details of this depend on implementation. In your example, your compiler is more likely to optimize it away entirely and directly access/modify the values in the vectors. In such case, `pFigure` (even as a value) may truly be an alias, not mapping to any physical variable at all.

> Is there any point to reference of pointer type?

Not unless you want to directly modify the pointer itself, as the other answer already states.