# What happens after C++ references are compiled？

Tags: c++, reference

After compilation, what does the reference become, an address, or a constant pointer?

I know the difference between pointers and references, but I want to know the difference between the underlying implementations.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int &b = a;
    int *ptr = &a;
    cout << b << " " << *ptr << endl;  // 1 1
    cout << "&b: " << &b << endl;      // 0x61fe0c
    cout << "ptr: " << ptr << endl;    // 0x61fe0c
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the assembly output suggest to you?

Comment: Note that reference is not an `object` in C++ Standard Speak https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object

Comment: Just for example, the same variable value, the same address can be found through a pointer or a reference, nothing special.

Comment: @BarryBao That's the point of references, once assigned, they are **inditinguishable** from the object they a refering to. In your example, `&b` and `&a` are the same thing. It's **impossible** to get the address of the reference itself.

Comment: Absolutely. It's the relationship between a person's nickname and a person's name.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67599356/is-there-any-point-of-reference-of-pointer/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pedantic answer is: Whatever the compiler feels like, all that matters is that it works as specified by the language's semantics.

To get the actual answer, you have to look at resulting assembly, or make heavy usage of Undefined Behavior. At that point, it becomes a compiler-specific question, not a "C++ in general" question

In practice, references that need to be stored essentially become pointers, while local references tend to get compiled out of existence. The later is generally the case because the guarantee that references never get reassigned means that if you can see it getting assigned, then you know full well what it refers to. However, you should not be relying on this for correctness purposes.

**For the sake of completeness**

It is possible to get *some* insight into what the compiler is doing from within valid code by memcpying the contents of a struct containing a reference into a `char` buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstring>

struct X {
    int& ref;
};

int main() {
  constexpr std::size_t x_size = sizeof(X);

  int val = 12;
  X val_ref = {val};

  std::array<unsigned char, x_size> raw ;
  std::memcpy(&raw, &val_ref, x_size);

  std::cout << &val << std::endl;

  std::cout << "0x";
  for(const unsigned char c : raw) {
      std::cout << std::hex << (int)c;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl ;
}
```

When I ran this on my compiler, I got the (endian flipped) address of `val` stored within the struct.

Comment: Yes, I just want to know more about this. You're quite right. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @BarryBao I've added some more details.

Answer (score 2):

it heavily depend on compiler maybe compiler decide to optimize the code therefore it will make it value or ..., but as far i know references will compiler like pointer i mean if you see their result assembly they are compiled like pointer.

Comment: Yes, it's the address at the end. Thank you for your answer. I don't want to be dead.